# Install package with pip that has additional qualifiers

Tags: pip, python-packaging

Our CI pipeline publishes wheels for branches that have a version of

```
<base version>-dev<timestamp>+<branch name>.p<pipeline id>
```

So if I am working on `cool-stuff` on in the `xyzzy` branch, it might upload a wheel for version `1.2.3.dev202211221111+xyzzy.p1234`

Somebody else, working in the `foobar` branch, might cause `1.2.3.dev202211221115+foobar.p1235` to be created.

How can I get pip to install the latest version from the xyzzy branch?  I tried `pip install cool-stuff>1.2.3.dev*+xyzzy` but it complained that it could not find a matching version (even though the available versions that it listed included a `+xyzzy` tag.)

`pip install cool-stuff==1.2.3.dev202211221111+xyzzy.p1234` did work, but I would prefer not have have to update the time stamp and pipeline number each time.  I am hoping to put `cool-stuff >= <magic>` in my config file and just run `pip install -e .` whenever I need new dependencies.

What format do I need to use here?

Comment: If I remember correctly it is not possible. The "local" part of the version string (in other words the part after the plus sign `+`) is not taken into account during dependency resolution. -- Maybe some helpful details here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers

Comment: I think I recall a very similar question being asked not too long ago (or maybe around the same time as yours). And I remember one of the most realistic solutions suggested was to let the CI pipeline generate distributions with multiple names. For example in your case the CI should generate wheels for `Library-foobar` and `Library-xyzzy`. If I were in your situation I guess that's the direction I would investigate. I can not think of a workable solution that would be based on the version string only.

Comment: @sinoroc Your suggestion would be feasible in my case.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it (and you'll get the bounty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible. I can not think of a workable solution that would be based on the version string only. The ["local" part of the version string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers) (in other words the part after the plus sign `+`) can not be used to differentiate between two releases as you intend to.

If I were in your situation, I think I would investigate a solution where the CI/CD pipelines generate distributions with a name customized according to the *git* branch. For example in your case the pipelines should generate wheels for `Library-foobar` or `Library-xyzzy`, depending on what branch is currently being worked on (while still keeping the same top-level import names of course). This assumes that you can customize your pipelines and processes deeply enough to support such a workflow.